# Get true sort value from Ranked Model on RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

With [ranked-model](https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model) gem everything is working as a charm, but it will be really really helpful having a way to return the true order position, i mean something like this:

Creating tasks with an specific order:

```
Task.create( name: 'Task A', row_order_position: 1 )
Task.create( name: 'Task B', row_order_position: 3 )
Task.create( name: 'Task C', row_order_position: 2 )
Task.create( name: 'Task D', row_order_position: 4 )
```

This will return the next results:

```
TaskA = Task.where(name: 'Task A')
TaskB = Task.where(name: 'Task B')
TaskC = Task.where(name: 'Task C')
TaskD = Task.where(name: 'Task D')
TaskA.row_order => -4194303
TaskB.row_order => 4526
TaskC.row_order => 0
TaskD.row_order => 88450116
```

And what i need is a way to get the next results:

```
TaskA.row_order_position => 1
TaskB.row_order_position => 3
TaskC.row_order_position => 2
TaskD.row_order_position => 4
```

Maybe i can get it with a method in the Task model, but i can't find the way to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: What does `task.row_order_position` return?

Comment: Task.order(:row_order_position).map(&:row_order_position)

Comment: `task.row_order_position` returns nil

Comment: @ilanberci, i didn't understand your solution, ordering is fine and working with `Task.rank(:row_order)`